# Parameter values with '+' sign and no spaces between characters is getting 404 Not Found in the Response URL

Tags: c#, api, parsing

I have a 'getCustomerDetails' function in my API that accepts one parameter 'customerName'. This 'customerName' parameter accepts the value from the selected value in a dropdown (ui). Some values from that dropdown has special characters like '%', '#', '+' and '*'. At first, I thought all parameters with special characters on its values would have a response of '404 Not Found' but upon checking, only values with a '+' sign in between characters are getting that response.

Please see below examples:

**Parameter value with no plus sign:** Test this one*and this one

**Result from the Network tab:**
[image: OK Response]

**Parameter value with plus sign in between characters:** Test+this one*and this one

**Result from the Network tab:**
[image: 404 Not Found]

I've read about encoding but I don't know where to implement it in my codes or what's the right thing to do about this.

Here's my get function in the UI. I'm using ReactJS here.

```
getCustomerDetails = (customerName) => {
      let url =
        Utilities.getApiHttps() +
        "CustomerModule/CustomerDetails/" +
        customerName;
      fetch(url, {
        headers: {
          "Cache-Control":
            "private, max-age=0,  no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=31536000",
          Pragma: "no-cache",
          Expires: 0,
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + Utilities.getToken(),
        },
        method: "GET",
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({
            CustomerDetails:
              data.CustomerDetails=== 0
                ? ""
                : data.CustomerDetails.toFixed(4),
            StartYear: {
              value:
                String(data.StartYear) === "0"
                  ? ""
                  : data.StartYear,
              label: data.StartYear,
            },
            EndYear: {
              value:
                String(data.EndYear) === "0"
                  ? ""
                  : data.EndYear,
              label: data.EndYear,
            },
          });
       })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
          this.setState({
            error: true,
          });
        });
    };
```

Here's the controller:

```
        [HttpGet("CustomerDetails/{customerName}")]
        public CustomerDetails GetCustomerDetails(string customerName)
        {
            CustomerDetails customerName = new CustomerDetails();
            ICustomerModuleServices customerModuleServices = new CustomerModuleServices();

            UserAccess usernameHasAccess = new UserAccess();
            usernameHasAccess = _utilities.CheckUserAccess(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);

            UserServices uService = new UserServices();
            string tokenForValidate = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString().Replace("Bearer", "").Trim();
            string USER_NAME = _tokenHandler.GetUserNameFromToken(tokenForValidate);

            if ((tokenForValidate != "") && (uService.ValidateToken(tokenForValidate)))
            {
                if (usernameHasAccess.hasAccess)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        details = CustomerModuleServices.GetCustomerDetails(customerName);
                        logsService.InsertUserAPIActivity("/CM/CustomerDetails", USER_NAME, "TEST", ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerName, _utilities.GetDefaultToolName());
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        string MethodName = ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
                        string Application = _utilities.GetDefaultToolName();
                        logsService.InsertAPIErrorLogs(GetType().Namespace, GetType().Name, MethodName, USER_NAME, exception, Application, "TEST");
                    }
                }
            }
            return customerName ;
        }
```

Here's my service for GetCustomerDetails:

```
public CustomerDetails GetCustomerDetails(string customerName)
{
    CustomerDetails details= new CustomerDetails();
    try
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_utilities.ADOConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetCustomerDetails_sp]"))
            {
                sqlCommand.Connection = conn;
                sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                conn.Open();

                sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@CUSTOMERNAME", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = customerName;

                using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        details.StartYear = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("StartYear")) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32 (reader.GetOrdinal("StartYear"));
                        details.EndYear = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("EndYear")) ? 0 : reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("EndYear"));
                        details.StartYearLabel = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("StartYearLabel ")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("StartYearLabel "));
                        details.EndYearLabel = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("EndYearLabel"))? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("EndYearLabel"));
                        details.Comments = reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("Comments")) ? string.Empty : reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Comments"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        ...
    }

    return details;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "are not being passed correctly"? What happens that shouldn't? What doesn't happen that should? Do you expect those characters to be wildcards of some sort?

Comment: More like they aren't being encoded correctly when they're being sent. Show the code that reproduces this; some html, javascript, controller code etc. Show both ends of the interaction (client and server)

Comment: Hi @CaiusJard , I've updated the post. Thanks

Comment: Hi @AKX please see updated post above. Thanks

Comment: This may have to do with the implementation of the `GetCustomerDetails` stored procedure, too. If possible, you should show that source too.